# Can I create Dataset in power BI Using Power Shell

Tags: powerbi

Actually I want to create dataset by using PowerShell, suppose I don't want to use power BI desktop to create Dataset and data source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a dataset either using [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/)'s [PostDatasetInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup) (using it with [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)) or using Microsoft's official [Power BI Management module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt/) and [Add-PowerBIDataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.data/Add-PowerBIDataset?view=powerbi-ps) cmdlet in particular.

For example, something like that:

```
Login-PowerBI

$col1 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name ID -DataType Int64
$col2 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name Data -DataType String
$table1 = New-PowerBITable -Name SampleTable1 -Columns $col1,$col2

$col3 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name ID -DataType Int64
$col4 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name Date -DataType DateTime
$col5 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name Detail -DataType String
$col6 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name Result -DataType Double
$table2 = New-PowerBITable -Name SampleTable2 -Columns $col3,$col4,$col5,$col6

$dataset = New-PowerBIDataSet -Name SampleDataSet -Tables $table1,$table2

Add-PowerBIDataSet -DataSet $dataset
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. I want to Connect With existing SQL server Database and want to create dataset.

Comment: If you know the schema, then simply provide [DatasourceConnectionDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup#datasourceconnectiondetails). If you don't know it, then first you must connect to the database and read the information about the columns of your tables, e.g. by reading from [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) dmv.

Comment: You can [refresh the dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) (if connection information is provided) or [push the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postrowsingroup) to it programatically.